# WPF : Referencing Assembly with Forms Controls does not work?

Tags: wpf, dll, reference

I've got a Problem. I need to use some classes from another Library DLL, that has been written a year ago, in my WPF Project. Therefore I reference this Library in my Project. But when I want to rebuild my solution I always get some warnings that my assembly cannot be resolved because it uses some dependencys that do not match my targeted framework.

This is one of the Errors

> The referenced assembly "istis.AcademyOne.ClassLibrary, Version=2.1.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fd9f6afaca722199, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project. A1RevisionControls

Does anyone know a workaround or a solution so I can keep the original DLL and use it in my WPF Application ?

EDIT : Ok I solved the Problem switching my Target Framework of my WPF Solution to .NET Framework 4.0 instead of Framework 4.0 Client Profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be to put the old dll behind a WCF facade. Another option would be to include the old dll in a new project, and use some sort of [inter-process communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28VS.85%29.aspx) like [named pipes](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/dotnetnamedpipespart1.aspx) to talk between the two.

Or you could just share the class files with a new .Net 4 class project, and reference that new class library. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685342/shared-data-object-between-wcf-service-and-silverlight-app) and [this example](http://10rem.net/blog/2009/07/13/sharing-entities-between-wcf-and-silverlight) talk about doing it in Silverlight and/or WCF, but the principle is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I solved the problem somehow on my own switching the target framework of my wpf solution